# Calculating Logarithms with Python

Tags: python, logarithm

I am trying to calculate logarithms using the math module of python `(math.log(x,[base])`, however when I use `float(raw_input)` for the x and base values, it gives me the error, `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`.

```
x = 9.0
base = 3.0
```

Comment: Also paste the actual code and traceback

Comment: Yeah give us an example of your input for x and base values

Comment: Are you trying to use `1` as the base?  That could cause this.

Answer (score 7):

Nonsense, it works perfectly well

```
>>> import math
>>> x=float(raw_input())
9.0
>>> base=float(raw_input())
3.0
>>> math.log(x, base)
2.0
```

Why don't you show us exactly how you reproduce the problem? wim is quite correct - a base of `1` will give that error

```
>>> base=float(raw_input())
1.0
>>> math.log(x, base)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

On the otherhand - if `x<=0` you get a "math domain error"

```
>>> x=float(raw_input())
0
>>> math.log(x, base)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid x<=0 as it is not defined !

Comment: Yeah, thats what i thought, but how do I avoid that? What if only want 3 instead of 3.1.

Comment: yes it should be an overflow error, if your x value is changing in a loop then you need to handle the case with an if statement and no, base=3.1 should not be a problem